# strange pathname?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

```
* (make-pathname :name "cgi-bin/")
#P"cgi-bin/"
* (merge-pathnames "nav.py" #P"cgi-bin/")
#P"cgi-bin/nav.py"    ; **it is ok**
* (merge-pathnames "nav.py" (make-pathname :name "cgi-bin/"))
#P"nav.py"            ; why ?

*(defvar bp #P"/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/")
* bp
#P"/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/")
* (merge-pathnames "nav.py" bp)
#P"nav.py"            ; why ?
* (merge-pathnames "nav.py" #P"/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/")
#P"/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/nav.py"    ; **it is ok**
```

I am using sbcl-1.0.54.

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `pathname` is a structure that represents a pathname using components, like *drive*, *host*, *directory*, *name*, etc. See [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#pathname) for more details.

You construct a `pathname` using `make-pathname` function with `:directory`, `:name` and other keywords, and the function returns an object of type `pathname`:

```
CL-USER> (defvar p (make-pathname :directory '(:absolute "home" "test" "docs")))
CL-USER> #P"/home/test/docs/"
```

The function `merge-pathnames` as documented [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_merge_.htm#merge-pathnames), completes the missing components of the *pathname* specified with the ones from *default-pathname*:

```
CL-USER> (merge-pathnames p "tada.txt")
CL-USER> #P"/home/test/docs/tada.txt"
```

Edit: it doesn't work for you because you are constructing a pathname with `:name` and that specifies the name of the file (without extension or `:type`). So when you call `merge-pathnames` it doesn't find a missing component in its pathname, because "cgi-bin/" is specified as `:name` (the filename), and you already got a filename in "nav.py".

Comment: See also the end of PCL's chapter on [Files and File I/O](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/files-and-file-io.html).